# Webpack config for SASS font imports to be one file with the SASS file?

Tags: javascript, angular, sass, webpack, angular-cli

I need to make one css bundle consisting the font files inside. No external files. Just one file.

This is my setup. I'm using Angular2, and my `Component` is set to `ViewEncapsulation.Native`, for some reason. I am requiring my SASS file (with font imports) in the `styles` properties inside the `Component` itself. I'm also using AngularCLI so I have no access to `webpack.config` directly so I use inline options in the `require` method.

What I have now is:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'lms-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styles: [
    require('./../../node_modules/foundation-sites/dist/css/foundation.css'),
    require('!css!sass!url!./../assets/vendor/fontello/scss/_fontello.scss').toString(),
    require('./../assets/vendor/fontello/scss/_animation.scss'),
    require('./app.component.scss')
  ],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.Native
})
export class AppComponent {
```